# Cookie not expiring per StartUp.cs settings

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-identity

I have tried a plethora of solutions over the course of 2 days and still have not been able to get this to work. What I want is for a user cookie to expire after a set amount of time 


E.g. User A logs in and goes to home page, User A goes for a lunch break. User A comes back and clicks on the nav bar and gets redirected to the login page.

I have tried everything from `AddAuthentication()`, `AddSession()` and `AddCookie()` options all having an `ExpireTimeSpan` and `Cookie.Expiration` of my choosing. Nothing seems to work. The project uses **ASP.NET Identity** and I am aware this service should be called before the cookie options. Please see my current `StartUp.cs` below, this is the last thing i tried:

#### Startup.cs

```
public class Startup
    {
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
        public IContainer ApplicationContainer { get; private set; }

        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => false;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });
            services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(config =>
                {
                    config.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
                })
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

            //other services e.g. interfaces etc.
            services.AddAuthentication().AddCookie(options =>
            {
                options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                options.Cookie.Expiration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60);
                options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
                options.LogoutPath = "/Account/Logout";
                options.AccessDeniedPath = "/AccessDenied";
                options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
                options.SlidingExpiration = true;
            });
            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
            //services.AddSession();

            var containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();
            containerBuilder.Populate(services);
            this.ApplicationContainer = containerBuilder.Build();
            var serviceProvider = new AutofacServiceProvider(this.ApplicationContainer);

            return serviceProvider;
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.ConfigureCustomExceptionMiddleware();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseCookiePolicy();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            //app.UseSession();
            app.UseMvc();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code isn't affecting the Identity cookie:

> ```
> services.AddAuthentication().AddCookie(options => ...);
> ```

Instead, it's adding a new cookie-based authentication scheme, named `Cookies`, and configuring *that*. With all the standard Identity setup, this scheme is unused, so any changes to its configuration will have no effect.

The primary authentication scheme used by Identity is named `Identity.Application` and is registered inside of the `AddIdentity<TUser, TRole>` method in your example. This can be configured using [`ConfigureApplicationCookie`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.identityservicecollectionextensions.configureapplicationcookie?view=aspnetcore-2.2). Here's an example:

```
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options => ...);
```

With that in place, the cookie options will be affected as intended, but in order to set a cookie with a non-session lifetime, you also need to set `isPersistent` to `true` inside your call to [`PasswordSignInAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.signinmanager-1.passwordsigninasync?view=aspnetcore-2.2#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Identity_SignInManager_1_PasswordSignInAsync_System_String_System_String_System_Boolean_System_Boolean_). Here's an example:

```
await signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(
    someUser, somePassword, isPersistent: true, lockoutOnFailure: someBool);
```